# Cannot upload a file to Azure Storage C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying a simple upload to Azure Storage in C#. It works for small files, but when I try to upload a file of 40mb, it just wont upload. I am stuck in upload for about 20 minutes and then I end up cancelling the call.

```
var storageConnectionString = "XXXXXXX";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //Gets the folder with the MediaID
            CloudBlobContainer videoscontainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("TestFolder");

            CloudBlockBlob videofile = videoscontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(("test" + ".mp4"));


            //Save blob contents to a temp video file.
            var videostream = new FileStream(@"XXXXXX.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            videofile.UploadFromStream(videostream);
            videostream.Close();
```

I have a decent internet so I am sure an upload of just 40mb cant takes more than 20 minutes to upload. The hardest part is, I don't know what error I am getting. I tried a manual upload in the storage and it finished in about 2 minutes.

EDIT: I just kept waiting until i got a callback and got this error.

Error:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The request was aborted: The request was canceled.",
    "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Core\\Executor\\Executor.cs:line 604\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamHelper(Stream source, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Blob\\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 411\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(Stream source, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Blob\\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 309\r\n   at StoneFunctions.Controllers.ValuesController.<UploadSingleFile>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Alan\\source\\repos\\Stone\\StoneFunctions\\Controllers\\ValuesController.cs:line 49\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The request was aborted: The request was canceled.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.ByteCountingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Core\\ByteCountingStream.cs:line 180\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions.WriteToSync[T](Stream stream, Stream toStream, Nullable`1 copyLength, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean calculateMd5, Boolean syncRead, ExecutionState`1 executionState, StreamDescriptor streamCopyState) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\Common\\Core\\Util\\StreamExtensions.cs:line 169\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Core\\Executor\\Executor.cs:line 670"
    }
```

Comment: Is it a blob Storage? You might take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets

Comment: @McBoman Does the error I am getting suggest issues with performance?

Comment: Try to set maxAllowedContentLength="51200000" to allow up to 50mb in web.config file as below and see if it helps,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="51200000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: @SwikrutiBose already tried that. I have it set to 2gb but still no luck.

Comment: Is `TestFolder` your actual container name, or did you modify it for Stack Overflow purposes? (just making sure this isn't one of your issues, as container names must be all lowercase)

Comment: @DavidMakogon yeah I modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the error is coming because of [`BlobRequestOptions.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.singleblobuploadthresholdinbytes?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes) value. This value essentially specifies the maximum size of the blob that can be uploaded without breaking it into chunks. If you don't specify any value for this property, the default value is [`128MB`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/3331c605fb2e07de5759da46b8f7086deb78a5a4/changelog.txt#L76). Since you're not setting this explicitly and your blob size is `40MB`, Azure Storage SDK is trying to upload this 40MB data in a single request without breaking it into chunks and that request is somehow timing out.

To solve this problem, please explicitly set this value to say `2MB` or `4MB`. Then the SDK will break your 40MB file in 20 (or 10) chunks and upload these chunks.

Here's the code I used:

```
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        client.DefaultRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024
        };
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("myblobcontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        var filePath = @"Full File Path";
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob name.exe");
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(fs);
        }
```

I uploaded about 60MB file using this code.

Comment: I have a question. It seems the file is broken into chunks of 4MB whatever value(of course <40MB) I specify. I find it in fiddler that the count of request is always 10, is it expected or have I misunderstood sth?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JerryLiu sorry for the delayed response. The number of requests should always correspond to how many blocks are you uploading (which in turn depends on the block size). So if you have a 40 MB file and you define 4MB block size, then you should see a total of 11 requests (10 for uploading these 4MB blocks and 1 for Put Block List request). Similarly if you define 1MB block size, then you should see 41 requests (40 for uploading blocks and 1 for Put Block List). Are you not seeing this behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it again just now, this time I upload a 75M file and define `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` 1M. And I found 19 block requsets and 1 blocklist request. In fiddler `Content-Length: 4194304` is shown in each block upload request header.

Comment: I haven't looked at the SDK code but it seems SDK is deciding the block size and setting it to 4MB.

Comment: How to use  BlobRequestOptions.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes ? Can you give an example  ? I just tried like this blob.uploadfromstream(filestream,null, new BlobRequestOptions() { SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 400000 }); But it didnt work.